# Python psycopg2 Caching?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Is it possible to store the executed `fetchall()` query from psycopg2 into memory, so that I don't have to run that again on my database with a million entries?

What's the best way to store them locally on a machine so that Python can any time dissect the `list`?

Comment: search for redis

Comment: `rs_list = cur.fetchall()`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Do you mean use fetchall() any time I need it? So I keep one cursor just for this?

Comment: `rs_list = cur.fetchall()` will fetch all the results into a `list` after that the cursor will no longer have the results. To get updated results you will need to run `cur.execute(<the_query>)` again and then do  `rs_list = cur.fetchall()`  again. Test it with a subset of the data.  Not sure why you want to do this any case?  You would probably be better served by a {server side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors).